# numerictextboxtargetelement does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, syncfusion

also getting error on TargetElement also does not exist, getting args.event only no TargetElement exist

```
<SFNumericTextBox TValue="int?" Value="10" CssClass="e-custom" ShowSpinButton="true" Change="OnValueChange" />
```

```
@code {
    private void OnValueChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        

        if (args.TargetElement == NumericTextBoxTargetElement.SpinUp)
        {
        }
        else if (args.TargetElement == NumericTextBoxTargetElement.SpinDown)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, this is not how [SyncFusion doc](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/numeric-textbox/events#valuechange) specifies you should do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ValueChange event for your requirement. The ValueChange event triggers when the NumericTextBox value is changed.
For your scenario, you can compare the previous value with the current value of the NumericTextBox component and then perform your own logic operations based on the result.

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs

<div style="margin:130px auto;width:300px">
    <SfNumericTextBox TValue="int?" Value="10" CssClass="e-custom" ShowSpinButton="true">
        <NumericTextBoxEvents TValue="int?" ValueChange="OnValueChange"></NumericTextBoxEvents>
    </SfNumericTextBox>
</div>

@code
{
    private void OnValueChange(ChangeEventArgs<int?> args)
    {
        var TempVlaue = args.PreviousValue;

        bool result = args.Value > args.PreviousValue ? true : false;

        if (result)
        {
             // Do something if spin up button clicked
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something if spin down button clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Numeric Textbox ValueChange: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/numeric-textbox/events#valuechange

List of Native events supported by Numeric Textbox: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/numeric-textbox/native-events#list-of-native-events-supported

Also, you can refer to the below sample for more information:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/NumericTextBox1682455549